# Generate link alongside dynamically generated table rows

Tags: javascript, html

The following code generates table rows when "+" link is clicked. 
How can I make the "-" link to be generated when the rows are being generated? 
I want it to be on every row generated. I tried by giving the link an id="remove" and included it in my script but it didn't work and it even made the rows to stop generating.

```js
var index = 1;
  function insertRow(){
   var table=document.getElementById("costsharing");
   var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
   var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
   var t1=document.createElement("input");
    t1.id = "crs"+index;
    cell1.appendChild(t1);
   var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
   var t2=document.createElement("input");
    t2.id = "protocol"+index;
    cell2.appendChild(t2);
   var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
   var t3=document.createElement("input");
    t3.id = "funding"+index;
    cell3.appendChild(t3);
   var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
   var t4=document.createElement("input");
    t4.id = "bclass"+index;
    cell4.appendChild(t4);
   var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
   var t5=document.createElement("input");
    t5.id = "sharing"+index;
    cell5.appendChild(t5);
   var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
   var t6=document.createElement("input");
    t6.id = "amount"+index;
    cell6.appendChild(t6);
  index++;
  }
```

```css
table td {
   position: relative;
   height: 25px;
  }
  table input {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   border: none;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
  <table class="inventory" id="costsharing">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th style="width: 20%;">CRS/Site</th>
     <th style="width: 15%;">Protocol/Project</th>
     <th style="width: 15%;">Funding Source</th>
     <th style="width: 25%;">Budget Classification</th>
     <th style="width: 10%;">Sharing</th>
     <th style="width: 15%;">Amount</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tbody1" class="tbody1">
    <tr>
     <td><a class="cut" id="remove">-</a><input type="text" id="crs"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="protocol"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="funding"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="bclass"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="sharing"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <a class="add" id="btnAdd" onclick="insertRow();">+</a>
```

```
<!--style.css -->

/* reset */

*
{
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* content editable */

*[contenteditable] { border-radius: 0.25em; min-width: 1em; outline: 0; }

*[contenteditable] { cursor: pointer; }

*[contenteditable]:hover, *[contenteditable]:focus, td:hover *[contenteditable], td:focus *[contenteditable], img.hover { background: #DEF; box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.5em #DEF; }

span[contenteditable] { display: inline-block; }

/* heading */

h1 { font: bold 100% sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.5em; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }

/* table */

table { font-size: 75%; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px; }
th, td { border-width: 1px; padding: 0.5em; position: relative; text-align: left; }
th, td { border-radius: 0.25em; border-style: solid; }
th { background: #EEE; border-color: #BBB; }
td { border-color: #DDD; }

/* page */

html { font: 16px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif; overflow: auto; padding: 0.5in; }
html { background: #999; cursor: default; }

body { box-sizing: border-box; height: 11in; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 0.5in; width: 8.5in; }
body { background: #FFF; border-radius: 1px; box-shadow: 0 0 1in -0.25in rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

/* header */

header { margin: 0 0 3em; }
header:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

header h1 { background: #000; border-radius: 0.25em; color: #FFF; margin: 0 0 1em; padding: 0.5em 0; }
header address { float: left; font-size: 75%; font-style: normal; line-height: 1.25; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
header address p { margin: 0 0 0.25em; }
header span, header img { display: block; float: right; }
header span { margin: 0 0 1em 1em; max-height: 25%; max-width: 60%; position: relative; }
header img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
header input { cursor: pointer; -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; height: 100%; left: 0; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; }

/* article */

article, article address, table.meta, table.inventory { margin: 0 0 3em; }
article:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }
article h1 { clip: rect(0 0 0 0); position: absolute; }

article address { float: left; font-size: 125%; font-weight: bold; }

/* table meta & balance */

table.meta, table.balance { float: right; width: 36%; }
table.meta:after, table.balance:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

/* table meta */

table.meta th { width: 40%; }
table.meta td { width: 60%; }

/* table items */

table.inventory { clear: both; width: 100%; }
table.inventory th { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }

table.inventory td:nth-child(1) { width: 26%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(2) { width: 38%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(4) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(5) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }

/* table balance */

table.balance th, table.balance td { width: 50%; }
table.balance td { text-align: right; }

/* aside */

aside h1 { border: none; border-width: 0 0 1px; margin: 0 0 1em; }
aside h1 { border-color: #999; border-bottom-style: solid; }

/* javascript */

.add, .cut
{
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;  
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0.6em;
}

.add, .cut
{
    background: #9AF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#00ADEE 5%, #0078A5 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00ADEE 5%, #0078A5 100%);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-color: #0076A3;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.333);
}

.add { margin: -2.5em 0 0; }

.add:hover { background: #00ADEE; }

.cut { opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -1.5em; }
.cut { -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in; }

tr:hover .cut { opacity: 1; }

@media print {
    * { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
    html { background: none; padding: 0; }
    body { box-shadow: none; margin: 0; }
    span:empty { display: none; }
    .add, .cut { display: none; }
}

@page { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Show us what you actually tried, instead of just telling us that it was “not working”.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anchor tag to the DOM tree in the insertRow function just like you added the input tags.

The insertRow function would become something like this:

```
var buttonShown = false;
var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
    var table=document.getElementById("costsharing");
    var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var t1=document.createElement("input");
    t1.id = "crs"+index;
    cell1.appendChild(t1);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var t2=document.createElement("input");
    t2.id = "protocol"+index;
    cell2.appendChild(t2);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var t3=document.createElement("input");
    t3.id = "funding"+index;
    cell3.appendChild(t3);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var t4=document.createElement("input");
    t4.id = "bclass"+index;
    cell4.appendChild(t4);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var t5=document.createElement("input");
    t5.id = "sharing"+index;
    cell5.appendChild(t5);
    var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
    var t6=document.createElement("input");
    t6.id = "amount"+index;
    cell6.appendChild(t6);
    if (!buttonShown) {
        var button=document.createElement("a")
        button.addEventListener("Click", removeRow, false);
        button.innerHTML = '-';
        table.parentNode.insertBefore(button, table.nextSibling);
        buttonShown = true;
    }

    index++;
}
```

You still have to write the removeRow function.

Comment: Still not working, I don't know if I'm not getting it right.

Comment: Did you write a removeRow function yet?

Comment: No Dennishofken, pardon me, I'm a newbie in javascript. So I wanted to figure out that soon after I find out how to make the "-" link to appear on every new row.

Comment: I made one last edit, could you try again with that code. Let me know which errors you get if theres any

Comment: Its still not working, its just generating new rows which don't have the "-" link and its not showing any errors.